# Get a percent of the total grouped by a field in sumologic

Tags: sumologic

I have the following query

```
_sourceCategory=MyAppSource "data_event" 
| json "fish" , "count", "method"
| count > 5 and method == "good"?1:0 as approved
```

This gives me something like

```
Fish      count      method   approved
catfish   7          bad      0 
pike      8          good     1
bass      2          good     0
catfish   6          good     1
pike      7          good     1
bass      2          bad      0
```

I'm trying to transform it to show the percentage of approved, grouped by fish
And maybe also the total count of fish

So for example

```
Fish     approved   count
catfish  50%        2
pike     100%       2
bass     0%         2
```

I realize i can `sum(approved)` and group the sum. I also know I can use `count` to get the total

So I could add the following

```
| count as total, sum(approved) as totalapproved group fish
```

But that just gives me

```
fish    total      totalapproved
catfish 2          1
pike    2          2
bass    2          0
```

Not sure how to pull the ratio of the two and maintain the group by fish aspect.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a lot simpler than I thought. I can add another expression at the end to give me what I needed

```
| (totalapproved/total)*100 as percent
```

This gave me the percentage and continued to be broken down by fish.

Comment: It would be great if you would show your entire query. I'm running into weird issues with my count and I'm curious what order you put everything in.